# Controlling a 3rd Party timer implementation in JavaScript Event Handler

Tags: javascript, jquery

I downloaded a countdown timer component [The Final Countdown](http://hilios.github.io/jQuery.countdown/), which I'm trying to implement on my site and control via button(s), but unsure how to adapt it to my website to work as user-triggered 30-day countdown clock.

I created a click event handler to detect button presses and verified that the handler is called, but I don't know how to make the timer start, pause or stop.
Rather, clicking the button always results in timer just continuing to countdown.

Any ideas how I can proceed with this?

**Configuring the timer :**

```
<div id="clock"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
   $('#clock').countdown('2017/02/10', function(event) {
      var $this = $(this).html(event.strftime('' +
         '<span>%w</span> weeks ' +
         '<span>%d</span> days '  +
         '<span>%H</span> hr '    +
         '<span>%M</span> min '   +
         '<span>%S</span> sec'));
   });
</script>
```

**Click event handler:**

```
<script>
    $(function() {
        var button = $('.start');
        button.click(function() {
            $(alert('It Worked') );
        });
    });
</script>
```

**Button declaration**:

```
<%= link_to 'Start My Whole 30!', '#', class: 'btn btn-success btn-lg start' %>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try making your `coundown` event handler conditional on some global variable being `true`, then toggle that state using the button.

pt. 1

```
  window.countingDown = true
  $('#clock').countdown('2017/02/10', function(event) {
      if (window.countingDown) {
        // do stuff
```

pt. 2

```
  button.click(function() {
     window.countingDown = ! window.countingDown
```

Comment: Thanks for the help.  I give this a shot and update the thread if I get it to work.